# Civ V bug in Linux - Free Thought policy is not available when it should

Tags: civilization-5, linux

I am playing the Linux version of the game from Steam.

I have adopted Rationalism after fully completing Patronage and tradition. In rationalism I have adopted secularism and humanism. At this point Free thought should be available but it's not.

It says: "This policy may not be adopted yet because prerequisite Policies have not been acquired."

I look the web and found the wiki on [social policies](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Social_policies_(Civ5)#Rationalism) which also seems to have inversed secularism and humanism. It is writen here that Free Thought needs Humanism when in the game the tree clearly indicate that you need secularism. Inverselly, Sovereignty in the game tree indicate that you need Humanism but in the wiki, it says you need Secularism.

Since it doesn't work in the game, I wonder if the wiki is correct! Can anyone confirm this.

Here is a snap shot of what I see in the game. (note that you don't see that I had Humanism and Secularism because when I decided to go for Commerce since this tree wasn't working, I lost all my policies in the rationalism tree! Probably another bug...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the in-game Civilopedia it is stated that Free Thought needs Humanism, which is also reflected (in the social policy chart) in the image below.

[image: Rationalism]

If you have a different policy tree, then it might be a bug, as the policy tree shouldn't change no matter which OS you are playing on.

Comment: Exactly! If I look at the tree in the game and the one you are showing me, they are not the same! Free thought is under Securalism and not Humanism! (Sovergnty is under Humanism). Also I encountered another bug when I choose Commerce Policy (since I wasn't able to select Free Thought), I lost all policies already gained in the rationalism tree (Humanism and Secularism)!!!

Comment: I edit my question and added a snap shot of the Rationalism tree. As you can see they do not match!

Comment: That is very strange. Either the Linux version is meant to be different, though i seriously doubt that, or its a major bug. You should probably contact support. :)

Comment: Or you should check with other Linux players, if you can.

Comment: Am I missing something? The two screenshots demonstrate the same policy progressions in my view.

Comment: No they don't, the second policies in the right and left trees are interchanged.